# How to write homebrew formula that keep their files in the Cellar?

Tags: homebrew, noweb

I'm trying to write a formula for the Icon programming language (necessary for noweb), but its binary distribution contains TONS of files (almost 1000) in the `lib/` directory. I'd like to leave them out of the symlink-to-`/usr/local/lib` process since I only need the dependency when building noweb.

Is there a way I can specify that an installation should be kept in its cellar only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, finally found the command. Something like:

```
keg_only "Icon has hundreds and hundreds of lib/ files so we leave them in the keg."
```

Alternatively, you may write

```
keg_only :provided_by_osx
```

to have it print the following as rationale: "This is because the formula is already provided by OS X."

Answer (score 0):

"keg_only" will keep *everything* from being linked in.

To keep "most" stuff from being linked in, you can install everything to "libexec" and then symlink from there to bin, or write shim-scripts to bin that call things out of libexec. Lots of Java brews use this method, see "ActiveMQ" or "Gant" for examples.